# Ruby on Rails - Validations and Before Filter method to substitute User Inputted Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, validation, gsub

In my Ruby on Rails app, I have a sign-up form, where users have to enter some data. I have strict validations that only allow entered values that are members of an array. This isn't part of my app, but it uses the same concept I want to apply.

Say I wanted to have a field where a user entered a superhero name. My validations would have an array like so.

```
SUPERHEROES = ['Batman', 'Superman', 'Captain America', 'Wonder Woman', 'Spiderman']

validates_inclusion_of :superhero, :in => SUPERHEROES
```

If a user entered Clark Kent, for example, the validations would fail. Given I created a new array.

```
ALIASES = ['Bruce Wayne', 'Clark Kent', 'Steven Rogers', 'Princess Diana', 'Peter Parker']
```

I'd like before the form is submitted (update action) for the values in the ALIASES array to be converted into the SUPERHEROES array.

I was thinking something like this could work.

```
def alias_to_superhero
  ALIASES.each_do |alias|
    i = 0
    while i < SUPERHEROES.length
      alias.gsub(alias, "#{SUPERHEROES[i]}")
      i++
    end
  end
end
```

And then at the top of my validations final I could have a line like this

```
before_update: alias_to_superhero
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate that `superhero` contains the hero or the alias name of an superhero. But after validation before save you replace aliases with the matching hero name. The benefit of replacing the alias with the hero name after validation is that you keep the users input untouched unless all validations succeed.

```
validates_inclusion_of :superhero, :in => SUPERHEROES + ALIAS

before_save :replace_alias_with_hero_name

private
def replace_alias_with_hero_name
  if ALIAS.include?(superhero)
    self.superhero = SUPERHEROES[ALIAS.find_index(superhero)]
  end
end
```

This solution only work when both arrays have the same size and the hero names and aliases are at the same position in the array. A more flexable version would perhaps operate on a hash like this:

```
HEROS => { 'SUPERMAN' => ['Clark Kent', 'C. Kent' ... ] ... }
```

Comment: Great answer, this one works. My only question is, should I create the method in my model file, or should I create it in my helpers file. I heard convention suggests placing method names in a helper file.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `before_validation` callback instead of `before_update`

```
before_validation: alias_to_superhero
```

Also you can check directly against inclusion of `ALIASES` or have a join array of both `ALIASES` and `SUPERHEROS` for validity.

Comment: Thank you. I was unsure of which before method to call, because they seemed pretty similar. But validation makes the most sense.